# How to do a main menu layout in Java?

Tags: java, swing, layout

I'm working with a few people to design a game for a project in class. While making the main menu GUI, I searched all over for some way to get the design the way I wanted ([here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ioFX5.jpg)), but I couldn't figure it out. CardLayout, BoxLayout, BorderLayout, GridLayout, none of those have helped in what I'm trying to do, at least not the way I was implementing each layout. Is there some other layout that could help me with aligning the title text and 4 buttons to the left (horizontally) and aligned with each other vertically. Is it possible to use GridLayout with maybe 5 rows and 3 columns and just fill the 2nd and 3rd columns with nothing? I also want there to be sufficient padding between each object and from the bounds of the window.

This is what I've got so far, but this spreads the width of all the buttons across the entire window:

```
    JLabel title = new JLabel("Inkball", JLabel.LEFT);
    JPanel panel = new JPanel();
    panel.setLayout(new GridLayout(5, 3, 0, 25));
    panel.add(title);
    panel.add(playNow);
    panel.add(highScore);
    panel.add(rules);
    panel.add(exitGame);
    Container c = this.getContentPane();
    c.add(panel, BorderLayout.CENTER);
```

Comment: Show us what you've done to try to solve your own problem to this point (hint: post code).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

- Start with a `BorderLayout`.
- To this, add a `JPanel` that uses either a `GridLayout` or `GridBagLayout`, to the `BorderLayout.WEST` position of the parent container, this panel will be used to layout the options on the right
- Add a `JPanel` with a `CardLayout` to the `BorderLayout.CENTER` position of the first container.  This will will allow you to switch between views based on the selection of the user.
- You will need to have the ability to obtain notification about user selection from the "menu pane" and update the "view pane".  You simply use a `ActionListener`, registered to the "menu pane", which acts a proxy for the buttons actions and provide information about what the action menus via the `actionCommand` property of the `JButton`s and `ActionEvent`

Have a look at [How to Use Buttons, Check Boxes, and Radio Buttons](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/button.html) and [Laying Out Components Within a Container](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/index.html) for more details

Comment: +1, for nesting panels with different layout mangers. I was in the middle of making this comment when the answer popped up saving me typing time :)

Comment: Thanks! Also, how can I format the buttons so that they're not all stuck together as one? All the buttons are touching each other and the left/bottom edge of the window, so is it possible to add some padding between each component?

Comment: @MadProgrammer For the actual JPanel that's currently holding each component, I'm using GridLayout (with 5 rows, 1 column, otherwise the buttons are lined up horizontally, not vertically)

Comment: @user2197420 Try using `GridLayout(int rows, int cols, int hgap, int vgap)`, which will allow you to specify the horizontal and vertical gap to use between the components